# To what value does the limit of the sum converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose $a$ and $b$ are real numbers and that $a<b$, to what value does
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow  \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n e^{a + i \frac{b-a}{n}} \frac{b-a}{n}$$
converge to?

Any insight on how to go about this? Would the answer be zero due to the $(b-a)/n$ factor?

Comment: Is this problem perhaps being given to you while you're discussing Riemann sums in class? Maybe you should try to view the problem from that lens.

Answer (score 2):

The index of the sum is $i$ and $a$ and $\Delta = (b-a)/n$ are independent of $i$. so you have
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n e^{a+\Delta i}\cdot \Delta
 = \Delta e^a \sum_{i=1}^n \left(e^\Delta\right)^i,
$$
and the sum becomes a straight-forward geometric series.

Can you complete it?

---

Alternatively, this looks like a Riemann integral with $(b-a)/n = \Delta$ so
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n e^{a+i\Delta} \Delta = \int_a^b e^x dx = e^b - e^a.
$$

Comment: wow I feel dumb for not seeing that! thanks! will give it another go now